# Basic encoding/decoding of characters for the web

Tags: html, dom, browser, xss, html-encode

I feel like this is something I should definitely know about, but I'm not entirely sure of the details of at what point a character is decoded by a browser (or even if I'm thinking about it in the right way).

While inspecting the DOM of a site to which I've added some content (through a form, for example), I can see my `<` (in the contents of my comment) appear as a string. Even if the angular brackets are well-balanced (e.g. `<something>`), it appears as a string rather than an element in the DOM. I appreciate this is critical in defense against injection attacks such as XSS, so (on the server), the content is written as a string literal rather than an element - but how does the browser recognise this and render it differently? And when does it decode it?

If the server does respond with `&gt;` or `&lt;` why do I not see this in dev tools?

My confusion comes from the fact that, when inspecting, there is no difference between my `<something>` content and a `<something>` element (if there were such a thing).

Comment: Please provide code which shows how exactly you're "adding some content".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think the addition of content is the most relevant here. My question is more specific to the response, not the request. Whether the `<` containing content is encoded or not on the way up, my question is what are typical browser requirements for displaying such characters without recognising them as DOM elements?

Comment: Are you returning a pure HTML document from the server, or are you "adding content" dynamically via Javascript…?

Comment: Sorry @deceze, I should clarify - let's suppose this is a 'comment' feature.  I've added a comment to the site, and the contents of my comment included `Here is some <comment> content`. This is posted to the server. When the server responds with it, the browser renders it out as content, as opposed to treating the `<comment>` part as an element. So, I'd expect to see (when inspecting the DOM) `&lt;content&gt;`, but it seems not. It's rendered just as an element would be. How has the browser distinguished between an element and content without this encoding? Or does dev tools hide encoding too?

Comment: Note, the above is great, it's expected behaviour, I wouldn't want to open my site up to XSS attacks. I'm more asking about the details of how the browser implements this decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I'd expect to see (when inspecting the DOM) `&lt;content&gt;`, but it seems not.

This is merely because your browser's DOM inspector is a bit loose in its representation. You're inspecting **the DOM** after all, a complex object oriented internal memory structure, yet your browser is showing it to you in an *HTML-like* presentation. Either because of an oversight or as a conscious decision to make this presentation more readable, not everything that should be an HTML entity in valid HTML is being displayed as HTML entity.

If you inspect the actual source code of the page, you'll see `&lt;content&gt;`.